# Is this question about the nature of an Echo Knight's Echo a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

Candidate for closure: [Is the Echo of a Echo Knight actually a creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178458/is-the-echo-of-a-echo-knight-actually-a-creature)

Dupe Target: [Does an Echo Knight fighter's echo provoke an opportunity attack when it moves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178207/does-an-echo-knight-fighters-echo-provoke-an-opportunity-attack-when-it-moves)

Is this question asking if the Echo Knight's Echo is a creature or not a duplicate of the question asking about the Echo triggering opportunity attacks?

Answer (score 6):

#### Closing it as a duplicate presumes a specific correct answer.

The argument is that it's redundant to ask question 2 (is the echo a creature?) because the answer to question 1 (does it provoke opportunity attacks?) already entails that. This envisions the answer to question 1 as a syllogism:

A. Only a creature can provoke opportunity attacks.
B. An echo is not a creature.
Therefore, C. An echo does not provoke opportunity attacks.

If that answer properly establishes its premises, it will contain an answer to question 2.

But **this is not the only possible answer**. In fact there are currently *three* answers to question 1:

- the accepted answer ("no"), which relies on that syllogism;
- an overwhelming upvoted answer ("yes") that directly contradicts the accepted answer;
- a moderately upvoted answer ("I don't know") saying the language is ambiguous.

Now, assuming the validity of premise A, the "yes" answer must *also* imply an answer to question 2--that the echo *is* a creature. However, the argument actually made by the "yes" answer is that *premise A is unreliable* (and it goes on to answer question 1 by considering other factors).

Closing question 2 as a duplicate therefore amounts to affirming premise A and rejecting the "yes" answer to question 1, and probably the "I don't know" answer as well.

**This is not what closing questions is for.** It's a janitorial tool for keeping the space clean and maintaining the quality of questions, not a device for declaring victory in arguments.

Comment: I think the core issue is that OAs are only done by creatures. So asking if X generates OAs, then it's asking at it's core if it is a creature. But that also seems separate enough. It's close!

Comment: @NautArch My position is that "OAs are only done by creatures" is a fairly fraught statement. It's not something we can just accept as a fact for purposes of site policy.

Comment: Is it, though? I mean, we are the experts here and I think that's fairly clear in that being a creature is the requirement. But I'm personally unconvinced it's a dupe (or that it's not a dupe.)

Comment: @NautArch I think the issue here is that we don't know if there are or would be other requirements to performing an Opportunity Attack other than being a creature and having a reaction; iirc, the Echo doesn't have its own actions or reactions and thus can't perform an Opportunity Attack anyway, so that wouldn't mean it is inherently not a creature.